# read / write properties file in xpages

Tags: java, xpages, properties-file

In my XPages app would like to add an UI to edit the content of a properties file. In the file I would like to store key/value pairs which I would like to use in my application.

Is this possible? Does anyone provide some guidance or example code where I can start with?

Comment: Can you post the code you have attempted?  Is there any other context we should be aware of (input, desired output)?

Comment: at the moment I am looking as example at http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1070 but I mainly want to have a single field / text area to edit the content of the properties file

Comment: The magic word is DXL Malin ;-)
I don't have any code example but it can be done. Check the OpenNTF API.

Comment: have look at the second blog of Sven Hasselbach, http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1763

Comment: I will do. Thank you!

Comment: I have called now at post of Sven Hasselbach and it turns out this works fine with files stored under the WebContent folder. But How can I assess files that are stored under the Resources\Files folder like my strings properties file ?